# java.lang.abstractmethoderror while Starting an Ignite

Tags: java, ignite

While Starting a Ignite node as Client, at the run time, getting a Error as **java.lang.abstractmethoderror**

Stack Trace of it as

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.hadoop.HadoopProcessorAdapter.validateEnvironment()V
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.createHadoopComponent(IgniteKernal.java:1160)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:884)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1739)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1589)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1042)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:964)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:850)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:749)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:619)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:589)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:347)
    at com.mstorm.ignition.Igniter.startIgnite(Igniter.java:47)

Igniter is a Clas which is staring a Client node, Code is as Follow,

*Ignition.setClientMode(true);

Ignite ignte = Ignition.start("ignite_config.xml");*

I am using same version of Ignite-core's Jar which have started the Server Ignite, as of Client Ignite.

Help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do? It looks like you downloaded the Hadoop Accelerator [1] build, but not actually using it. If that's the case, you should download the fabric build instead.

[1] https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/hadoop-accelerator

Comment: I am just starting a Ignite in Client mode. It works well and good on my local machine but when I deploy a JAR on server. it gives me such error.

Comment: Also my pom.xml is as follow, 
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
 </dependency>


     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
     <artifactId>ignite-hadoop</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.0</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: OK, why do you include `ignite-hadoop` then?

Comment: There was multiple versions of ignite-hadoop on Server, Issue Solved Thanks